# Is it possible for standalone flash exe file to load/run external files/image?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I trying to create a Flash based e-Brochure which will be basically loading from a CD. I wanted to load certain images from the CD and also open some pdf which are in the CD itself. Is this possible with flash?

Answer (score 0):

You can load external resources and open `http` links in browser with standalone .exe application, however I'm not sure if you can open pdf files easily with `navigateToURL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use AIR not flash for that purpose. You can bundle air runtime into your app (you can look e.g. [here](http://www.riaspace.com/2011/08/bundling-air-3-runtime-in-air-desktop-applications/)). From AIR app you can work with any data on CD.

Answer (score 0):

Images, audio, video and text files... no problem. I've done lots of CD based presentations using flash and ActionSctipt 2.0 and 3.0.

I've even used the [Gaia Framework](http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/), which I highly recommend, for CD based stuff. It takes no time to setup and preload all your files into Flash.

PDF files you will not be able to import. However, there are ways of haveing Flash open/execute them.